# Yii2 Drop Down List Not Saving To Database

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

I made a model `AssignForm` as :

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class AssignForm extends ActiveRecord
{
public $username;
public $organ_name;
public $role;

}
```

And I added `actionAssign` function in `SiteController` as :

```
public function actionAssign(){

        $model = new AssignForm();


        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){

            Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                ->update('users', ['post' => $model->post], "username = '$model->username' ")
             ->execute();

        }


        return $this->render('assign',['model' => $model]);

    }
```

And as `view` I have `assign.php` file :

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?php

echo $form->field($model, 'username')->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Users::find()->all(),'id','username'),
[
        'prompt' => 'Select User!!'
]);
echo $form->field($model, 'role')->dropDownList(['0' => 'employee', '1' => 'responsible'],['prompt'=>'Select Option']);
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

That shows currect information but it doesn't save to database. But when I use below code in `actionAssign` it works fine :

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                ->update('users', ['post' => 'ssss'], "username = 'soghra' ")
                ->execute();
```

But I want to write using database informations.
How can I dynamically add to database??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have any technical problem ..I 've just passed wrong arguments(`username` instead of `id`).
Sorry for interruption.

as below :

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->update('users', ['post' => 'ssss'], "id = 'soghra' ")
            ->execute();
```

hope this will be helpfull

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I edited my answer ... check it out